# Can anyone confirm if my answer is right?

Tags: calculus

Find the critical points and the intervals of the increase and decrease of the function  $ f(x)=(x+5)^2(x-2)^5 $

The critical points are : $ -3,\ -5,\ 2 $

The four intervals -

from left to right these open intervals are $(-\infty,-5),\ (-5,-3),\ (-3,2) \ \text{and} \ (2,\infty) $

**This part I am not sure of:**

On the interval $(-\infty,-5)$, $f(x)$ is decreasing

On the interval $(-5,-3)$, $f(x)$ is decreasing

On the interval $(-3,2)$, $f(x)$ is increasing

On the interval $(2,\infty)$, $f(x)$ is increasing

Comment: How did you work out the last part? It's not correct. The first part is fine, though.

Comment: @Infiaria the one about the decreasing and increasing (the one I am not sure about)?

Comment: @Infiaria if its that one that I just assumed since its in the negative its decreasing and then as it is approcing postive its increasing

Comment: Are you finding points on $f'(x)$ or $f(x)$? If $f'(x)$ is positive at that interval it's increasing, and if it's negative it's decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share something I learnt for this. Its called the sign scheme. To check a function's behaviour whether it is increasing or decreasing we find critical points.

A critical point is a point where the function behaviour or sign changes. Usually it would change from + to - or vice versa.

Let us find the critical values first for the function $f(x)=(x+5)^2(x-2)^5$, since we want to find whether the function is increasing or decreasing in a particular interval we will calculate the derivative first. If the derivative is positive the function increases if negative then the function decreases. This change in the increasing and decreasing behaviour occurs at the critical points.

So $$f'(x)=2(x+5)(x-2)^5+5(x+5)^2(x-2)^4$$

$$f'(x)=(x+5)(x-2)^4(2x-4+5x+25)$$

$$f'(x)=(x+5)(x-2)^4(7x+21)$$

To calculate critical points just equate this with $0$, to get

$$7(x+5)(x-2)^4(x+3)=0$$

Critical points are: $x=-5$ with multiplicity $1$, $x=2$ with multiplicity $4$ and $x=-3$ with multiplicity $1$.

Now plot these points on the number line:
[image]

Whenever there are critical points like this for a polynomial, the function is always positive beyond the maximum critical point. For this case the maximum critical point is $x=2$, so the sign is + beyond $[2,\infty)$

Going from right to left whenever a critical point comes the sign changes $m$ times where $m$ is the multiplicity of the critical point. So at $x=2$ the sign changes $4$ times from + to - to + to - to +. So the next interval is + in the interval $[-3,2)$ till the next critical point $x=-3$.

At $x=-3$ the sign changes only once from + to -. So the sign is - from $[-5,-3)$.

At $x=-5$ the sign change only once from - to +. So beyond $x=-5$, the sign is +.

To compile everything just see the interval where the function $f'(x)$ is - it is decreasing and where it is + it is increasing. Remember the sign scheme was applied on the function $f'(x)$ to find whether $f(x)$ increases or decreases.

The function is increasing in the interval : $(-\infty,-5)\cup[-3,2)\cup[2,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,-5)\cup[-3,\infty)$

The function is decreasing in the interval : $[-5,-3)$

Hope this helps...

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

$f´(x) = [(x+5)^2]´(x-2)^5 + (x+5)^2[(x-2)^5]´$

$f´(x) = 2(x+5)(x-2)^5 + 5(x+5)^2(x-2)^4$

$f´(x) = (x+5)(x-2)^4[2(x-2) + 5(x+5)]$

$f´(x) = 7(x+5)(x+3)(x-2)^4$

Your break points are: $-5, -3, 2$

Using a sign analysis you find out the intervals to be:

**Increasing on**: $(-∞,-5)\cup(-3,2)\cup(2,∞)$

**Decreasing on**: $(-5,-3)$

Comment: but the critical points I found, the website gave it to me as being correct

Comment: it was different that your critical point

Comment: So in my case, it will be decreasing, increasing, decreasing, increasing (in the order I have written above)?

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake there...

Answer (score 0):

First your critical points should be $$x=-5,-1.5,2$$
Since $$f'(x)= 4x^3+18x^2-22x-60$$ 
and we look at the interval $$\infty<x<-5$$ and its sign (f'(x)) is negative in that interval so it is decreasing. Next we look at $$-5<x<-1.5$$ where the sign of the differential is positive so it is increasing. Then $$-1.5<x<2$$ where again the differential is negative so decreasing! Finally $$2<x<\infty$$ where the sign is positive so increasing!

Hope this helps!

Comment: my critical points, according to the website, is correct. Thus, it is different that yours

Comment: So in my case, it will be decreasing, increasing, decreasing, increasing (in the order I have written above)?

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/function-critical-points-calculator/critical%20points%20f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%3D%5Cleft(x%2B5%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%5Cleft(x-2%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D